# Firebase 3.6.0 - Login Authentication - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I've recently moved from Parse to Firebase due to it shutting down. However, I am now encountering many issues. I'm just testing logging in using this code in my AppDelegate class. Whenever I run this, I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` on the class. How exactly do I fix this?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: "test@test.com", password: "123456", completion: { (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print(user?.email)
        }
    })

    return true
}
```

Pod file

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Fire' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Fire
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Invites'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/AppIndexing'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  target 'FireTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'FireUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Current error in the console:

```
objc[7008]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x118b4f910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x1188e2210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-09-30 14:05:44.946754 Fire[7008:562611] bundleid: Natural-Development.Fire, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:44.947828 Fire[7008:562611] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.063385 Fire[7008:562826] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.063945 Fire[7008:562826] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.074818 Fire[7008:562825] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.089816 Fire[7008:562611] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.112479 Fire[7008:562611] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCNetworkReachability, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.114628 Fire[7008:562611] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.114948 Fire[7008:562611] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution app-measurement.com:0, flags 0x4000d000
2016-09-30 14:05:45.115464 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=::.0 ttl=60
2016-09-30 14:05:45.115 Fire[7008:562611] Configuring the default app.
2016-09-30 14:05:45.115705 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.232:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.116125 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.221:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.116941 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.117411 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.117625 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.221:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.118892 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.216:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.119183 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.119420 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.216:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.119694 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.216:0@0 = 144.131.80.221:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.119926 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.236:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.120200 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.120391 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.236:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.120679 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.236:0@0 = 144.131.80.221:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.137009 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.236:0@0 = 144.131.80.216:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.138700 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.251:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.141072 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.150509 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.251:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.151327 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.251:0@0 = 144.131.80.221:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.152173 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.251:0@0 = 144.131.80.216:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.152589 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.251:0@0 = 144.131.80.236:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.152901 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.227:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.153323 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.153781 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.227:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.154232 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.227:0@0 = 144.131.80.221:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.154963 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.227:0@0 = 144.131.80.216:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.155176 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.227:0@0 = 144.131.80.236:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.155547 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.227:0@0 = 144.131.80.251:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.155937 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.247:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.156468 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.156915 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.247:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.157129 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.247:0@0 = 144.131.80.221:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.157679 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.247:0@0 = 144.131.80.216:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.157 Fire[7008:562611] Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
2016-09-30 14:05:45.158122 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.247:0@0 = 144.131.80.236:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.158717 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.247:0@0 = 144.131.80.251:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.159778 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.247:0@0 = 144.131.80.227:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.160491 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=144.131.80.217:0 ttl=375
2016-09-30 14:05:45.161141 Fire[7008:562846] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.161647 Fire[7008:562847] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 play.googleapis.com 443
2016-09-30 14:05:45.162382 Fire[7008:562825] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-09-30 14:05:45.163649 Fire[7008:562847] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
2016-09-30 14:05:45.164405 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.232:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.165486 Fire[7008:562611] subsystem: com.apple.securityd, category: OSStatus, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.165396 Fire[7008:562847] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to play.googleapis.com:443
2016-09-30 14:05:45.166691 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.221:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.166: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to remove checkin auth credentials from Keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
2016-09-30 14:05:45.167485 Fire[7008:562848] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 2 plus.google.com 443
2016-09-30 14:05:45.168079 Fire[7008:562847] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7f95227046a0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.168586 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.216:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.168951 Fire[7008:562848] [] tcp_connection_start 2 starting
2016-09-30 14:05:45.169: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Error failed to remove all tokens from keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
2016-09-30 14:05:45.169287 Fire[7008:562847] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting
2016-09-30 14:05:45.169565 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.236:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.169854 Fire[7008:562848] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to plus.google.com:443
2016-09-30 14:05:45.170508 Fire[7008:562847] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 play.googleapis.com:443 initial path (null)]
2016-09-30 14:05:45.171: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-09-30 14:05:45.171: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
202016-09-30 14:05:45.174 Fire[7008:562611] A reversed client ID should be added as a URL scheme to enable Google sign-in.
16-09-30 14:05:45.171034 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.251:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.186541 Fire[7008:562848] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7f9522406890
2016-09-30 14:05:45.186901 Fire[7008:562847] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 play.googleapis.com:443 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-09-30 14:05:45.188 Fire[7008:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3402000 started
2016-09-30 14:05:45.189 Fire[7008:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see google link)
2016-09-30 14:05:45.191242 Fire[7008:562817] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 3 device-provisioning.googleapis.com 443
2016-09-30 14:05:45.192630 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.227:0@0
2016-09-30 14:05:45.195343 Fire[7008:562847] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1 play.googleapis.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-09-30 14:05:45.196090 Fire[7008:562817] [] tcp_connection_start 3 starting
2016-09-30 14:05:45.196 Fire[7008:562611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.appinvite', reason: 'App Invite configuration failed.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110f4b34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011058f21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110fb4265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Fire                                0x000000010c31cc93 -[GINInvite(FIRApp) configureAppInvite:] + 978
    4   Fire                                0x000000010c31c892 +[GINInvite(FIRApp) receivedReadyToConfigureNotification:] + 154
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ee919c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ee909b _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ee8e02 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110eabea2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110eaaf3b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
    10  Foundation                          0x000000011005713b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    11  Fire                                0x000000010c22414a +[FIRApp sendNotificationsToSDKs:] + 296
    12  Fire                                0x000000010c222fee +[FIRApp configureDefaultAppWithOptions:sendingNotifications:] + 324
    13  Fire                                0x000000010c222cfb +[FIRApp configure] + 302
    14  Fire                                0x000000010c1ddda4 _TFC4Fire11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryVSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyP____Sb + 100
    15  Fire                                0x000000010c1de774 _TToFC4Fire11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryVSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyP____Sb + 180
    16  UIKit                               0x000000011136568e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000111367013 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
    18  UIKit                               0x000000011136d3b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    19  UIKit                               0x000000011136a539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114ebb76b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114ebb5e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114ebb96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ef0311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ed559c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ed4a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ed4494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000111368db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    28  UIKit                               0x000000011136ef34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  Fire                                0x000000010c1dfccf main + 111
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001135aa68d start + 1
    31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
2016-09-30 14:05:45.196440 Fire[7008:562825] [] sa_dst_compare_internal 144libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
.131.80.217:0@0 = 144.131.80.247:0@0
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a couple of things that went wrong,

1. You did not install firebase/auth pod.
2. The firapp is not done configuring itself and you are calling a firebase function right away.

I think is most likely to be the first one. In that case open the podfile and add pod 'Firebase/Auth'

This question was solved by not installing all of Firebase's features/pods.

Comment: @MaxKrissigo Weird.. then try not signing in and just creating a user.. since I assume you dont have any users in your firebase app.. Although trying to do that will only return an error.. maybe also trash the .localizedDescription.. just print error

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. When running this code i get Thread 1: signal SIGBRT at the top of the class where it says class AppDelegate. I've also added a user already manually on the database.

Comment: @MaxKrissigo you could also try to fix your conditional since it will always print nil, because the user do exists so its different from nil so it will print an error that do not exists. Are you using the xcworkspace ?

Comment: @MaxKrissigo are you importing firebase in the app delegate?

Comment: Yes I have imported it

Comment: I tried changing the if staetment to             if error == nil {
                print(user?.email)
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
still the same error

Comment: @MaxKrissigo the conditionals were not the problem because they were using optionals, it was just to avoid confusion. Are you using any other code besides this? I copied and paste your code to my app and it run without any errors

Comment: No, I'm not. Very odd. Would the error in the console be of any use? If so I'll add it to the post

Comment: @MaxKrissigo Do you have the config file in your project?, (Check that it doesnt have any numbers by the end like (1) or (2)). If that doesnt work, try not using every firebase feature if you are not going to use it, that may also be the cause.

Comment: The config file is all correct, I'll test out removing some of the other features. I just added them so it will just be easier later on not needing to add them.EDIT: It worked yay, thanks!